# Token undefined in interceptor

Tags: angular, jwt

I have been having a problem with using JWT for authenticating users and allowing access to certain areas of a site I'm working on.

Confirming the user exists in the database works fine and I can create tokens on the backend with no problems but when I try to use the token in my interceptor it doesn't work. This is my login function.

```
getToken() {
    // get token returns undefined
    return this.token;
}

    userLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    const authData: AuthData = { email: email, password: password };
    this.http.post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', authData).subscribe((response) => {
        const token = response.token;
        this.token = token;
    });
```

The token is declared as a private variable which is why I have the gettoken function which I use in the intercepter below.

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserAuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: UserAuthService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('auth-interceptor.ts intercept() Token = ', this.authService.getToken());
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        const authRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
        });
        return next.handle(authRequest);
    }
}
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: add a `console.log(response.token)` in order to see if you get a token or not. Also make sure to have  `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` in the `UserAuthService`

Comment: I definitely do receive the token from the back end. I added console.log within the response section of my HTTP request and one directly after but still in the login function and the token seems to be immediately being unset. I don't understand why that is though

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your interceptor in your module:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

Comment: ah sorry forgot to include that in the question. I have that. The problem I seem to have is the token is set and then immediately unset.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you should make sure to have `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` in your service otherwise the Service might not be a Singleton and you will have multiple instances of the class. This could explain why the token is missing.

also a trick to see what is happening, change the code like this:

```
  private _token: string;
  get token(): string {
    console.log('getting token: ', this._token);
    return this._token;
  }
  set token(token: string) {
    console.log('setting token: ', token);
    this._token = token;
  }
```

you can then simply do `this.token = token;` and `const authToken = this.authService.token;` and you should see the logs.

also add a `console.log()` in the service constructor in order so see if you have multiple instances of the same service.